# Track where 404s come from in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to figure out how visitors are getting to my /error404 page. I want to see what URL they attempted to visit (e.g., http://mydomain.com/iloveyou) before they received the 404, so I can see what content my users think I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get by without touching your source files--as long as your error pages/templates are tagged, that's all you need, configuration-wise.

As an aside, our error page template all look about the same so to clearly allow a person viewing the GA data to distinguish the various error pages, we annotate them by passing in a descriptive string to _trackPageview(), e.g.,

```
pageTracker._trackPageview("404_removed_directory");
```

Needless to say, this annotation is just for GA, it isn't shown to the user.

So w/r/t viewing the information you are after--i.e., page paths in which one of your error pages is the terminus--you can use either the GA data browser or either of the two [GA APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html).

---

***Using the GA Data Export API***

I would code my Request this way:

```
dimensions=ga:previousPagePath
metrics=ga:pageviews
filters=ga:nextPagePath%3D~SomeErrorPage.html
# or if your API client does not require URL encoding, then: 
filters=ga:nextPagePath=~SomeErrorPage.html
```

If you haven't used the *GA Data Export API*, the [Data Feed page](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html) shows a complete API Request that you can use as a template.

In addition, Google's *[Data Feed Query Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html)* is a decent sandbox to interactively test the queries that comprise your Requests.

---

***Using the GA data browser***

From the main Dashboard, on the left-hand side panel, click *Content*, then click *Overview* underneath it. To the right, in the main window, you will see a heading under the *Pageviews* chart, called *Navigation Analysis*, this has two linked options under it, *Navigation Summary* and ***Entrance Paths***. clicking the latter will reveal the view shown below. In the textbox, just enter the name of your error page to get the entrance path for that error page.

---

Finally, relying on your server access log for this information is less reliable for all of the usual reasons (caching, etc.), in addition, given your question is specific to GA, i assume you already use GA, so modifying your config file, and parsing the activity log, if you are not already doing so, is a lot of trouble, compared to getting a more accurate count of the same data through a channel (GA) you have already set up.

[image]

Comment: When I did this, my 'started here' column is blank. I have 'Analyze "ENTRANCE PATHS" Content "MY 404 PATH"'...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need google analytics for this - just expand the logging of your webserver to log referer data for this specific page. With this information you can see where the majority of people are coming from.